# Is there a way to animate and switch the positions of two Spinners in a single Activity on the same layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, layout

I have created a currency converter app.

I have two spinners in the activity. 
from currency --> Spinner1
to currency --> Spinner2

spinner1 and spinner2 contains a list of currency names.

a button just below these two spinners named, "Convert":
Button --> starts an asynctask to do the conversion and updates the textview at top with the result.

beside the Convert button, I have a reverse button. It actually switches the coversion. USD--to--EURO becomes EURO--to--USD and gives the result perfectly.

But on pressing the reverse button, I would like to implement an animation and  make the spinner1 to go to spinner2's position in the layout and the viceversa.

Can we animate and switch the positions of the spinner (keeping the selection intact) on clicking on a reverse button ?

Comment: Why do you need the animation?  Why not just bind the appropriate options to both spinners in your activity?

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it? I am fine without animation, but would look great with one.

Comment: Yes you can make an animation. Use translate on X-Axis for First Spinner to move to posx+50%, and for Spinner 2 to move to 0

Comment: It worked. Thanks.